# Как преобразовать коллекцию данных

Tags: javascript, map-reduce

Как преобразовать структуру:

```
[
 {
    "ID": "R01010",
    "NumCode": "036",
    "CharCode": "AUD",
    "Nominal": 1,
    "Name": "Австралийский доллар",
    "Value": 55.2845,
    "Previous": 54.731
 },

 {
    "ID": "R01020A",
    "NumCode": "944",
    "CharCode": "AZN",
    "Nominal": 1,
    "Name": "Азербайджанский манат",
    "Value": 47.9438,
    "Previous": 48.0446
 },
 
 {
    "ID": "R01035",
    "NumCode": "826",
    "CharCode": "GBP",
    "Nominal": 1,
    "Name": "Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства",
    "Value": 101.9621,
    "Previous": 101.8171
 },
];
```

В такую структуру:

```
 {
  'AUD': 55.2845,
  'AZN': 48.0446, 
  'GBP': 101.9621
 }
```

на ванильном js ?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: По какому принципу в результате должно получиться `'AZN': 48.0446,`, а не `'AZN': 47.9438,`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

коллекция.reduce((acc, el) => (acc[el.CharCode] = el.Value, acc), {})